# Do I need to wait for DOM-readiness to add a class to <body>?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Right below the start of the `<body>` tag, I want to include a script that will, among other things, add a class to the `<body>` tag.

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if(conditionIsMet) {
      document.body.className += ' condition-is-met';
    }
  </script>
  <!--
    ...
    ...
    ...
  -->
</body>
```

I know that, if I want to do heavy DOM manipulation like adding children to the document, I should use a DOM-ready function to ensure that the document tree has fully loaded. However, is it safe to access and manipulate `document.body` before the DOM tree has loaded?

Comment: I've never had any problems with anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely safe. Once the tag is opened, the element has already been created.

That said, you probably shouldn't be doing it this way.
Way don't you put all of your Javascript code before the `body` closing tag?

Comment: In general scripts go at the end of the body, yep. However, I'm planning to hack together a SOPA blackout tomorrow, and rather than mess with the core codebase I'm gonna use the site's announcement feature to quickly insert a bit of HTML. So the script will actually end up somewhere near the top of the body, where I'd normally put an announcement paragraph. I know it's not great practice, but the ease seems to significantly outweigh other concerns this time around :)

Comment: Thanks for putting my mind at ease, and, so long as no one swoops in pointing out an issue, I'll accept this answer as soon as the site allows :)

Comment: @Matchu - Good for you for supporting the SOPA opposition! [Check this out](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WP-SOPA-Blackout#readme).

Comment: Cool cool cool! It's not a Wordpress site, so I'm still gonna have to do a bit of my own stuff, but neat to know that people are making it so easy to speak up :)